# Python: How to reuse http connection to IP address (no host name)

Tags: python, python-2.7, httpconnection

I know that python urllib3 by default reuse http connection for requests sent to a same host. I wanted to have it work for requests sending to ip address. I did a little test:

```
import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
s = requests.Session()
print(s.get('https://<ip address here>/xxx/yyy',verify=False))
print(s.get('https://<same ip address here/xxx/yyy>',verify=False))
```

output:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1):...
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: ...
```

**second code:**

```
import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
s = requests.Session()
print(s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789'))
print(s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/anothercookie/123456789'))
```

output:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): httpbin.org
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
```

Obviously http connect was not reused (I mean w/o close nor drop) for ip address host, how can I make it work? or it's just impossible in the first place?